# Pagination from API Node.js (POKEapi) for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I've written code using POKEapi which shows me number of 150 pokemons.

I just started to learn js, it's my first app in node.js.

The point is, I need to make paginate this to show for ex. 9 pokemons per page. I tried to use something like this but it doesn't seems to work (.js).

I already have a looop, which get 150 links with pokemon data, so I thought I can somehow make it, that this loop will get for example 9 links, then shows it, adds the counter every iteration, and start the same loop but with updated counter once again (on the second, third..) pagination.

Tell me what do you think about bc I'm fighting with this and have no clue how to do this.

Here is the code I wanted to use:

```
const count = 0;
const limit = 9;
const fetchPokemon = (inType) => {
  console.log(inType);
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
    count++;
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
    promises.push(fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()));
    if (count === limit) {
      break;
    }
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    let pokemon = results.map((data) => ({
      name: data.name,
      id: data.id,
      image: data.sprites["front_default"],
      type: data.types.map((type) => type.type.name).join(", "),
    }));
    if (typeof inType != "undefined") {
      pokemon = pokemon.filter((row) => row.type.includes(inType) === true);
    }
    console.log(pokemon);
    displayPokemon(pokemon);
  });
};


const displayPokemon = (pokemon) => {
  const pokemonHTMLString = pokemon
    .map(
      (pokeman) =>
        `
<li class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="${pokeman.image}"/>
    <h2 class="card-title">${pokeman.id}. ${pokeman.name}</h2>
    <p class="card-subtitle">Type: ${pokeman.type}</p>
</li>
  `
    )
    .join("");
  pokedex.innerHTML = pokemonHTMLString;
};
```

The working code right now : (.js)

```
"use-strict";

const pokedex = document.getElementById("pokedex");
const dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
console.log(pokedex);
const fetchPokemon = (inType) => {
  console.log(inType);
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
    promises.push(fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()));
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    let pokemon = results.map((data) => ({
      name: data.name,
      id: data.id,
      image: data.sprites["front_default"],
      type: data.types.map((type) => type.type.name).join(", "),
    }));
    if (typeof inType != "undefined") {
      pokemon = pokemon.filter((row) => row.type.includes(inType) === true);
    }
    console.log(pokemon);
    displayPokemon(pokemon);
  });
};
const displayPokemon = (pokemon) => {
  const pokemonHTMLString = pokemon
    .map(
      (pokeman) =>
        `
<li class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="${pokeman.image}"/>
    <h2 class="card-title">${pokeman.id}. ${pokeman.name}</h2>
    <p class="card-subtitle">Type: ${pokeman.type}</p>
</li>
  `
    )
    .join("");
  pokedex.innerHTML = pokemonHTMLString;
};
fetchPokemon();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll benefit from separating your data from how you present the data (ie, model/view separation). Since there are a limited number of Pokemon, you can load them all once, then have a separate function to filter and deal with smaller sets of them. For example:

```
const fetchPokemon = () => {
  console.log(inType);
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
    promises.push(fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()));
  }
  return Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    return results.map((data) => ({
      name: data.name,
      id: data.id,
      image: data.sprites["front_default"],
      type: data.types.map((type) => type.type.name).join(", "),
    }));
  });
};

const getPokemonOfType(allPokemon, inType) {
  if (inType) {
    return allPokemon.filter((row) => row.type.includes(inType));
  }
  return allPokemon;
}

const displayPokemon(pokemon, start, limit) {
  const pokemonHTMLString = "";
  for (let i=start; i<limit && i< pokemon.length; i++) {
    const pokeman = pokemon[i];
    pokemonHTMLString += `
<li class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="${pokeman.image}"/>
    <h2 class="card-title">${pokeman.id}. ${pokeman.name}</h2>
    <p class="card-subtitle">Type: ${pokeman.type}</p>
</li>
`
  }  // end for-loop

  pokedex.innerHTML = pokemonHTMLString;
}

// so first you'd get all like this:
const allPokemon = await fetchPokemon();
// then you can get just the types you want:
const fatOnes = getPokemonOfType(allPokemon, "fat");
// then display as many as you like:
displayPokemon(fatOnes, 18, 9); // show from 18 through 26
```

By separating the loading of the data from the filtering and from the display, you get flexibility to do what you want, and each function does a specific job that can be understood and independently tested.

Comment: Thank for your replay. I have already filtered pokemon of types. 

I will try to use your DisplayPokemon way 

I will let you know :) 

```const fetchTypes = () => {
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      // console.log(data);
      const typesHTMLString = data.results.map((row) => `<option value=${row.name}>${row.name}</option>`);
      // console.log(types);
      dropdown.innerHTML = typesHTMLString;
    });
};
fetchPokemon();
fetchTypes();
```

Comment: my point is more about separation of duties. you might want to filter in a number of ways so better to not re-fetch from the api call if you don't have to do it again for a new filter type